# can't install FTDI vcp serial usb driver on osx yosemite

Tags: macos, usb, ftdi

[**environment**]

hardware / AE-UM232R(FT232RL) /  [circuit picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxZWF.jpg)

http://akizukidenshi.com/download/kairo/%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF/RS232%E3%83%BBUSB%E9%96%A2%E4%BF%82/L023_FT232RL%20USB%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB.pdf

PC / osx yosemite 10.10.5 , mac bool pro late 2013

Allow apps download from: Anywhere

---

[**problem**]

i can't find serial device.

```
ls -l /dev/*serial* 
No such file or directory
```

---

[**tried log**]

--- 1 ---

base FTDI driver off.

```
cd /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns 
mv AppleUSBFTDI.kext AppleUSBFTDI.disabled 
reboot
```

--- 2 ---

install FTDI vpc driver 2.3

i dont know why, install directory is /Library/Extensions

major case at internet: /System/Library/Extensions

--- 3 ---

load driver

```
cd /Library/Extensions
sudo kextload FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext 
kextstat | grep FTDI 
com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver (2.3)
```

--- 4 ----

load check

```
kextstat | grep FTDI    
155 0 0xffffff7f82b0f000 0x7000 0x7000 com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver (2.3) <92 38 5 4 3 1>
```

--- 5 ----

i can't find serial device.

```
ls -l /dev/*serial* 
No such file or directory
```

--- 6 ---

after Several tens of seconds,  FTDIUSBSerialDriver is dissapper

```
kextstat | grep FTDI    
don't exist
```

---

[**I noticed things**]

i checked /var/log/syslog　Statement of the following were a lot

```
"The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device."
```

i thought usb cable is broken, i changed usb cable.
but nothing changed.

Comment: I'm stuck with the exact same problem, did you find any solution for this ?